# What is Pyomo errorcode: 0? It occurs with every single example I run and I cannot solve it

Tags: python, pyomo

I am a student learning the Pyomo framework for constrained optimization, and I have been using the Springer "Pyomo - Optimization Modeling in Python" book as reference.

Originally, I set up Pyomo and the gurobi and glpk solvers through Anaconda (using the conda command), and the installation went without a hitch. I had been going through several examples in order to learn Pyomo, and had run into no problems with the *pyomo solve* subcommand on the Anaconda terminal.

However, I have had to buy a new computer and consequently reinstall and set up Anaconda and Pyomo on my new computer. I have followed the same installation steps as before, and run the previous example code to make sure that my installation is correct. The problem is that all of my previous code runs- and gives the correct results- but now there is an additional output at the end of my code that says *errorcode: 0* followed by *reval: instance: xxx*

This can be exemplified in the following picture: [pyomo solve output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgKt0.png)

The error and the subsequent *retval: instance: xxxx* lines appear in all of my examples, regardless of whether I use the gurobi or glpk solver. I am getting the right results, but I am concerned about this error and I wonder if this may affect other code that I am writing.

I anybody would be able to indicate what this error means, what the retval: instance: output is indicating, and how to solve it I would highly appreciate it.

Cheers!